# Prove without induction that the sequence $a_{n}=1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$ $=$ $\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+2}}$ with $a_1=2$ where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

While trying to prove that the sequence $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}$ with $a_1=2$ converges to Phi(the second sequence obviously converges to Phi), I recognized the pattern when I calculated the first couple terms.

I proved it with induction but I can't find any other way to prove the equivalence. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried proof by induction?

Comment: @Sil Yes and it worked, but I want to understand the relation between the two sequences so I want a direct proof. Using induction doesn't seem satisfactory since I practically just guessed the relation.

Comment: It is better to see it in the framework of the so-called **continued fraction expansion** of $\Phi$. See for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07384.pdf).

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that edit. Anyway there is nothing wrong in "guessing" and then proving, but I guess there will be alternative proofs.

Comment: You can write the Fibonacci recurrence as $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n}=1 + \frac{1}{\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}}$.

Comment: @dxiv That's kind of working backward from the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @Kaind That's just writing the known Fibonacci recurrence in an equivalent way that happens to match OP's recursion. Once that's established, you have two sequences with the the same recurrence relation and the same initial conditions, so there is nothing left to prove.

Answer (score 1):

we demand $a_n = \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ with $\gcd(p_n, q_n) = 1$ and $q_n \geq 1$   This is unambiguous, we are writing the fraction in lowest terms.

Next, $$  p_{n+1} = p_n + q_n \; , \; \; \; q_{n+1}  = p_n  $$
in which we may confirm the new denominator and denominator are coprime.

Finally $$ p_{n+2}  = 2 p_n + q_n= p_n + (p_n + q_n) = p_n + p_{n+1} \; . \; \; $$

along with
$$  q_{n+2} = p_n + q_n = q_{n+1} + q_n $$

That is the familiar recurrence for Fibonacci or Lucas numbers.  One may finish by finding the explicit fractions that show $p_1, p_2, p_3 .$ Apparently $a_1 = 2 = \frac{2}{1}$ and $a_2 = \frac{3}{2}$ and $a_3 = \frac{5}{3}.$

To get the Lucas numbers, begin with $a_1 =3$

Note that the recurrences $  p_{n+2} =  p_{n+1} + p_n $ and    $  q_{n+2} =  q_{n+1} + q_n $are just Cayley Hamilton for

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&1 \\
1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$